# Random curve made by points only

Tags: java, math, graphics2d, splines

I need to create a random curve like this:

[image: A random curve]

In this picture there are 3 examples, marked as follows:

1. The red oval is beginning of the curve and
2. The blue oval shows the end.
3. Between them are points marked with green ovals.

I only can use Point because after making one of these I need to create another small curve for each of the Point in previous curve. I tried with sin function or cos function but it work sonly if x or y point is the same for both start and end point.

Does anyone know how it's possible to this with Graphics2D and Point?

Comment: Those curves aren't random. They're parametric. Lookup splines, in particular cubic Bézier splines, and perhaps Hermite interpolation.

Comment: Well i need to create any type of Curve but Pixel by Pixel ( Point by Point) that is the problem . I can't write a code to make a points for example:

Point[] p = {(X1,Y2),(X2,Y2) etc }
Every point has a -1 or 1 pixel + last one and together they create a curve.

Comment: Why not just just compute the points in a point-list? Then do whatever you like with them. The algorithm is recursive, but not too difficult.

Comment: I don't know how the make algorithm :/ that is the point of this question . i am trying this for 5 days 10 hours a day and i can't get it to work.

Comment: So basically you want to know how spline interpolation works and implement it by yourself?

Comment: I know how it works i don't know to implement it in java code. from point to another point.

Comment: ok, see edit. Hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [Bezier Curves](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/BezierLab.htm).

If you to have a y-value for each x-value on your curve, then you could take a look at the [apache commons implementation](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/math/analysis/interpolation/SplineInterpolator.html#line.67). What you get here is a [PolynomialSplineFunction](http://commons.apache.org/math/api-1.0/org/apache/commons/math/analysis/PolynomialSplineFunction.html), which you can use to calculate any point on your curve.

```
SplineInterpolator interpolator = new SplineInterpolator();
PolynomialSplineFunction f 
         = interpolator.interpolate(xValues, yValues); //red and blue dots
f.value(4.0); //gets y-value for  x = 4.0
```

Comment: I can't use Bezier Curves . Please read the question . I need point by point or pixel by pixel creation of curve . If it was that simple i wouldn't ask.

Comment: Well i need to create any type of Curve but Pixel by Pixel ( Point by Point) that is the problem . I can't write a code to make a points for example:

Point[] p = {(X1,Y2),(X2,Y2) etc }
Every point has a -1 or 1 pixel + last one and together they create a curve.

Comment: Thanks for help . But this function are not existing in java

Comment: You are right. They are no included in the jdk, but you can download the apache common math library from http://commons.apache.org/math/.

Comment: Yea . But i can't use it it is a school project . They not allow as to use liberies :/ thank you anyway :)

Comment: @VukVasi It is definitely ok to ask questions about homework/school projects on Stack Overflow. To learn the most from doing so, you can follow the community wiki/guidelines that are published here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions -- best wishes

Comment: PolynomialSplineFunction is a one dimensional function - putting in the x values for middle curve which are not increasing will have odd effects. You probably need to use a parametric value `v` and express `x` and `y` as two functions of `v` rather than expressing `y` as function of `x`